How to let cmake linking qt5 and not qt?
I include lines:
#Add Qt5
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(proton_beam Qt5::Widgets)

in the CMakeLists.txt.
However, after I do cmake ../, I have
CMakeFiles/proton_beam.dir/build.make:proton_beam: /usr/lib64/libQt5Widgets.so.5.15.9
CMakeFiles/proton_beam.dir/build.make:proton_beam: /usr/lib64/libQtGui.so
CMakeFiles/proton_beam.dir/build.make:proton_beam: /usr/lib64/libQtCore.so
CMakeFiles/proton_beam.dir/build.make:proton_beam: /usr/lib64/libQtCore_debug.so
CMakeFiles/proton_beam.dir/build.make:proton_beam: /usr/lib64/libQt5Gui.so.5.15.9
CMakeFiles/proton_beam.dir/build.make:proton_beam: /usr/lib64/libQt5Core.so.5.15.9

where I do not have /usr/lib64/libQtGui.so and causing error while making it.
Thanks a lot of anyone can give comments. I tried to follow application is linking with both qt5 and qt4
by export QT_SELECT = qt5, but it is not working. I am on a remote server so cannot qtchooser
I will trying to build with cmake with qt5 but seems make file linking libQtGui.so at the same time.
The entire CMakeLists.txt is following:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project(ProtonBeamSimulation)

# Find Geant4 package
find_package(Geant4 REQUIRED)

# Include directories
include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src)
include_directories(${Geant4_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${ROOT_INCLUDE_DIR})

# Compile options
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER g++)
add_definitions(-std=c++11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

# Locate sources and headers for the project
file(GLOB sources ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cc)
file(GLOB headers ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.hh)

# Add the executable
add_executable(proton_beam proton_beam.cc ${sources} ${headers})

# Link Geant4 libraries
target_link_libraries(proton_beam ${Geant4_LIBRARIES})

# Link ROOT libraries
find_library(ROOT_CORE_LIBRARY Core HINTS ${ROOT_LIBRARY_DIR})
find_library(ROOT_HIST_LIBRARY Hist HINTS ${ROOT_LIBRARY_DIR})
find_library(ROOT_RIO_LIBRARY RIO HINTS ${ROOT_LIBRARY_DIR})
target_link_libraries(proton_beam ${ROOT_CORE_LIBRARY} ${ROOT_HIST_LIBRARY} ${ROOT_RIO_LIBRARY})

#Add Qt5
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets REQUIRED)

target_link_libraries(proton_beam Qt5::Widgets)

# Set the path for the executable
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR})

# Copy the necessary macro files to the build directory
configure_file(init_vis.mac ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/init_vis.mac COPYONLY)
configure_file(run.mac ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/run.mac COPYONLY)


Looks correct from the first glance. Could you maybe provide a minimal reproducible example? Or at least the full CMakeLists.txt?

@Kane Hi, I have update the full CMakeLists.txt

I don't have all these libraries. But after commenting them out everything works as expected. My theory would be that one of these libraries of yours bring Qt4. To verify, please try printing out Geant4_LIBRARIES, ROOT_CORE_LIBRARY, ROOT_HIST_LIBRARY and ROOT_RIO_LIBRARY variables to see what you are linking to.
